# What's the purpose of deny all anonymous policy

Tags: security

When we configure anonymous policy for a web application, there is an option for "deny all". Why is that?

We can just disable anonymous access, right?

Why would we enable anonymous access and use a "deny all" policy? Why would we use a "deny all" policy if the anonymous access is disabled?

Answer (score 1):

Policy will change. Management will change. Everything will change. **Deny all** option give you a quick way to change back if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

> **Deny All** -  Anonymous users cannot have any access, even if site administrators specifically attempt to grant the anonymous user
>   account access to their sites.

For more information about it, see [Manage permission policies for a web application in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ff608071.aspx) and also [Overview of security groups in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/cc261972.aspx)

Comment: Please feel free to mark it as an answer, if it has helped you because it might help someone in future too :). For more information, please drop a comment.